# How to use BBM in Blackberry Webworks?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks, bb-messenger

I am developing an application where I need to use BlackBerry Messenger (BBM) in it. As I am new to BlackBerry development, I don't know how to do it.

Actually, I have gone through many sites and I came to know that I need to install **BBM SDK**. As I am developing my application using **BlackBerry Webworks**, I want to know how to integrate **BBM** in **BB Webworks**, and other thing is as per one note in BlackBerry site as: **"The BlackBerry Messenger platform does not support 64-bit Java, or Java 7. "**

As I am using **Windows 7 (32 bit version)**, I think that Java installed in my desktop is 64-bit. So, does the following **BBM** works in my system otherwise I need to go for Java with 86-bit.

As I am new to this development, any small help will be appreciated.